# Declaring Java object given its type/class name as string

Tags: java, class, casting

I was wondering whether it is possible to declare a new object of some given type in Java, given that I have that type represented as a Class object.

For instance, let us say that I have

```
SomeClass obj1;
Class c = obj1.getClass();
```

Now I would like to take "c" and use it to declare a new object of that type. Something along these lines:

```
Class<c> my_new_var;
```

such that my_new_var would then be a variable of same type/class as obj1. This is directly related, I guess, to whether we can use a Class object (or something related to that Class object) as a *type* in the declaration of a new variable.

Is that possible, or impossible since Java is strongly-typed?

Thanks in advance,

Bruno

Comment: Such dynamic trickery is even discourages in dynamic languages. Why do you think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
YourType newObject = c.newInstance();
```

But you need to have a no-arg constructor. Otherwise you'd have to do more reflection.

Note that there is no need to cast if your `Class` is parameterized. If it is not, as in your code, you'd need a cast.

To your 2nd question - no, it is not possible to declare a variable of a dynamic type, because yes, java is statically typed. You must define the type of a variable at compile time. In the above example you can:

- use `Object`, if you don't know the type, because it is the superclass of all objects.
- use generics. For example (with exception handling omitted):

  ```
  public static <T> T createNewInstance(T exampleInstance) {
     return (T) exampleInstance.getClass().newInstance(); 
  }
  ```

Comment: Provided that your class has a public no-parameter constructor.

Comment: Thanks Bozho. I understand that c.newInstance() would give me a new object of same type as obj1; the problem is that when declaring newObject, I'd still need to declare it as "YourType", which I assume I don't know except via "c". Ideally I'd find that something like Class<c> can be used as a type when declaring a new variable -- such that I could do Class<c> newObject = c.newInstance(), but I understand that this might be impossible since Java is statically typed. Am I right? Thanks once again!

Comment: As in my 2nd example with `T` (or `Object`) you can postpone the declaration of the actual type. But at some point you will need to know the exact type. If you don't need it (in order to call methods on it), then you can simply refer it as `Object`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a default constructor:

```
SomeClass obj2 = (SomeClass) c.newInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks Adbullah. I understand your solution, but notice that SomeClass, in your command, is exactly the type/class represented by c, which in this case I assume I don't know (except via c). Ideally what I'd like to find is that something like Class<c> can be used as a type when declaring a new variable -- such that I could do something like Class<c> newObject = c.newInstance(), but I understand that this might be impossible since Java is statically typed. Am I right? Thanks once again!

Comment: In any object oriented language you have to know the type of something before you can do anything with it. In Java this can be an interface or a base class, and you can cast to either one. Without knowing anything else it is only an Object and there's very little you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, try:

That a = [c.newInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29);

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Class c  = Class.forName("com.xyzws.SomeClass"); 
Object a = c.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_new_var` would be of type `Class<SomeClass>` , which is not the same as `obj1` which is of type `SomeClass`.

However `my_new_var.newInstance()` does give you a new object which is of the same type as `obj1`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this:

```
SomeClass obj1 = ...
Class<? extends SomeClass> c = obj1.getClass();
SomeClass obj2 = c.newInstance();
```

This requires a no-arg constructor on whatever subclass (if any) of `SomeClass` `obj1` actually is.

However, this only works because you know the type of the `Class` object in question. Given some arbitrary raw `Class` or `Class<?>` object, you would not know what type of object `newInstance()` would return and you would only be able to declare that instance as an `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked:

```
Object innerObj = classObj.getClass().newInstance();
```